# Sum range in column with condition in another colum

Tags: excel, sum, conditional-statements

I´m trying to sum the values of a range in a column if the values in another column are equal to a certain number. For example (this is a very small example):

[image]

I want to sum all the values in Column C that in the same row have the number "2" in column A. For example the total with this condition should be 236. Can anyone help me? I´m not even getting a code to make anything. Thanks!

Comment: Using what? Excel? Or is it a view to a database?

Comment: Excel. I´m trying to write a VBA code for this but i´m not getting it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the D column with something like `=if(Ax="2"; Cx; 0)` and then sum the D column. This doesn't use VBA and need a column but is very simple and just works.

Comment: This would not even work.. How this was accepted as answer baffles me.

Comment: Doug, you are right about ==, = is better. I understood the question to be the sum on any condition. The equality test on an other column is just an example of his needs. SUMIF is enough for this particular need. My solution solve the general question.

Answer (score 6):

```
=SUMIF(A:A, 2, C:C)
```

That is all you need. This will sum all of C:C where 2 is found in A:A.

Comment: Thank you both! I was complicating but this is very easy! Thanks for your time!